# Cannot insert new Employee entity using InsertOnSubmit()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm facing this exception `An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext. This is not supported`. when I try to insert a new entity into my Employees table (the master one).

There is a relationship between the master Employees table and the details Orders table, and I'm sure that the relationship between these two tables (and specifically Employee.Orders EntitySet) is the cause of the problem since when I removed the relationship, it returns back to insert into Employees table with no problems.

When I searched for the problem, there was [this blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2007/12/25/117984.aspx) which I tried to implement but my case is a different than the one in the blog post in these items:

- He faces the exception when tries to update (while I try to insert).
- The tables architecture is different.

how can I solve this problem?

Here's the insertion code:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.Name = empName;    // empName is a local variable

// What should I default emp.Orders to?

dc.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(emp);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

**P.S:** My DataContext is defined on class-level in my repository and the exception is being thrown when I call `dc.SubmitChanges();`. and I didn't **Attach** any object why does it say that?

Comment: Should I drive a marketing campaign so I can get an answer to this question? I mean it is SO, something is wrong.

Comment: Do you have more than one Datacontext file in your solution?

Comment: DataContext file? I think you mean *.dbml file, no, I have only one.

Comment: No, `Employee` has an ID (int identity column) as a primary key.

Comment: Does the Employees entity have any relationship?

Comment: I've had similar problems before. It would be very difficult to locate the issue without having access to your dbml and all code surrounding both the object you're inserting and the dc you're using it with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article explaining what you need to do using the Attach and Detach methods:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/linq-to-sql-detach.aspx

Comment: Well, it didn't solve my problem and the example source code in full of compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it is trying to save something else besides just the employee object or you aren't showing us the full code in your repository.  When you instantiate your DataContext object (dc) try setting  DeferredLoadingEnabled = false, and ObjectTrackingEnabled = false and see if it works.  If it does, try watching the SQL code in SQL Server Profiler and see if it is modifying other objects that may have came from a different context like the message says.

```
var dc = new MyDataContext() 
{ 
    DeferredLoadingEnabled = false, 
    ObjectTrackingEnabled = false 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My bet is on the primary key.

- Are you sure the primary key is also set on `auto increment`?
- Did you
  try changing the name, does it work then?
- What happens if you remove
  all rows from your DB? can you insert one then?